# SQL Query to do a reverse CONTAINS search?

Tags: sql, regex

I need to search for Article Tag strings that are sub-strings of a user entered string.

So in the below example, if a user searched for "normal", the query should return Article 1 and Article 3, as article 3 has a wildcard tag "norm*".
If I searched for "normalization" then i should get back articles 3 and 4.
Let me know if I need to explain my question more clearly.

Example-

- Article 1 Tag = normal
- Article 2 Tag = apple
- Article 3 Tag = norm*
- Article 4 Tag = normalization
- Article 5 Tag = corvette

Note - I only need to do the substring search on tags that end with an *

Comment: what database are you in?  This might be more complicated as '%' is the like wildcard

Comment: select * from article where id not in (select id from article where tag like "foo")

Comment: Regex and wildcard's don't mix.

Comment: Can you break up the data so #3 would be two columns: `norm | true` and #1 would be `normal | false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, but perhaps not the most efficient, is to replace all `*` by `%` in your table and use `LIKE` statment  :

```
SELECT
  Tag
FROM
  Article
WHERE
  'normal' LIKE REPLACE(Tag, '*', '%')
```

See an example in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a928/3/0)

Comment: +1 Clever, and better performance than my awful solution. I considered this, but didn't think it would work so I never tried it ;)

Comment: Thanks this seems to work in SqlFiddle, hopefully it will work in Sqlite (win8 universal app).  The tried it with %norm and %norm%, and it seems to work correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think this query should work, although I didn't test it beyond your sample data.

Also, you didn't specify what database you're using and I just tried it on MS SQL, but it should be easy to adapt to other databases as it only relies on charindex and left (or substring) and those functions should be available on most databases.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8834/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table your_table (article varchar(10), tag varchar (20))
insert your_table values 
('Article 1','normal'),
('Article 2','apple'),
('Article 3','norm*'),
('Article 4','normalization'),
('Article 5','corvette')
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @str varchar(30) = 'normalization'

select t.article, tag 
from your_table t
left join (
    select 
       article, 
       left(tag, charindex('*', tag,0)-1) t, 
       charindex('*', tag,0)-1 as l 
    from your_table 
    where charindex('*', tag,0) > 0
    ) a
on t.article = a.article
where (tag = @str) or (left(@str, l) = t)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8834/1/0)**:

```
|   ARTICLE |           TAG |
|-----------|---------------|
| Article 3 |         norm* |
| Article 4 | normalization |
```

**Query 2**:

```
declare @str varchar(30) = 'normal'

select t.article, tag 
from your_table t
left join (
    select 
       article, 
       left(tag, charindex('*', tag,0)-1) t, 
       charindex('*', tag,0)-1 as l 
    from your_table 
    where charindex('*', tag,0) > 0
    ) a
on t.article = a.article
where (tag = @str) or (left(@str, l) = t)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8834/1/1)**:

```
|   ARTICLE |    TAG |
|-----------|--------|
| Article 1 | normal |
| Article 3 |  norm* |
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking was the only solution, but I figured it would be slow if the client eventually inputted a lot of data.  If psadac doesn't work in sqlite, I will try this answer.  It is always great to have options! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server then you can do like this:
I mean 
if it ends with *, then check whether the substring exists, 
otherwise match directly

```
    SELECT * FROM Articles
    WHERE
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(Articles.Tag, 1) = '*'
        CHARINDEX(LEFT(Articles.Tag, LEN(Articles.Tag) - 1), GivenStr)
    ELSE
        Articles.Tag=GivenStr
```